# DataGridView - multiple images in one cell with dragdrop

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a DataGridView, and I'm wondering if the below is easy to do, or indeed possible:

I want a column in the DGV that will be able to show multiple small thumbnails of images (very small, around 16 x 16). There will usually be 1-2 images, however there could be possibly be up to 30 so I'd love to be able to increase the row height if need be rather than have an extremely wide grid.

What makes it a bit more tricky is the following requirements:

- The ability to hover or click over each thumbnail, which will display the full size image
- The ability to drag a thumbnail from one row to another row

I'm relatively new to Windows Forms development, as I've only been using ASP.NET until now, so it's all a bit scary for me! Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

Comment: would you pls take a look at this link   http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/Images-from-file-into-datagridview    and  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/MultiEditDataGridView.aspx